# Groovy script is not executing in the Camel (Project)

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, apache-camel

Scenario: Just wanted to transfer the files from one location to another 
 location using camel and groovy script

Problem: I am not seeing any errors in the console, but how can we make 
 sure script is executing.

Sample MainApp Program  :

```
class MainApp {


    static void main(String... args)  {
        def camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext()

        println("printing something in the console MainApp")
        camelContext.addRoutes( new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            void configure() {
                println("Printing some thing before queue")
                from("Test").to("Test")
                println("printing something after queue")
            }
        })
         //camelContext.start()

       // Thread.sleep(10000)
       // camelContext.stop()

    }

}



Output :

sampling ...
include patterns:

org\.apache\.camel\..*
exclude patterns:
printing something in the console MainApp
Printing some thing before queue
printing something after queue

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Pom.xml file: If you could observe, below file contains all the jar files which are related to groovy and camel.. (I am thinking there are problems with pom file.. please let me know if you are finding out the same)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>SampleCamelProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-example-groovy</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <name>SampleCamelProject</name>

       <properties>
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <maven-resources-plugin-version>3.1.0</maven-resources-plugin-version>
        <maven-eclipse-plugin-version>2.10</maven-eclipse-plugin-version>
        <exec-maven-plugin-version>1.6.0</exec-maven-plugin-version>


        <camel-core-version>2.13.3</camel-core-version>
        <camel-groovy-dsl-version>2.19.5</camel-groovy-dsl-version>
        <camel-jetty-version>1.6.0</camel-jetty-version>
        <log4j-api-version>2.11.1</log4j-api-version>
        <log4j-core-version>2.11.1</log4j-core-version>
        <log4j-slf4j-version>2.11.1</log4j-slf4j-version>
    </properties>


    <description>A Camel route using Groovy DSL</description>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-groovy-dsl</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-groovy-dsl-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- used for jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-jetty-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-api-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-resources-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                    <!-- set verbose to be true if you want lots of uninteresting messages -->
                    <!-- <verbose>true</verbose> -->
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9.2-01</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.3-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-eclipse-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                        <classpathContainer>GROOVY_DSL_SUPPORT</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Allows the example to be run via 'mvn compile exec:java' -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec-maven-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.apache.camel.MainAppTest</mainClass>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jdk9-build</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>9</jdk>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <!--Skip compile on Java 9 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10905 -->
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-compile</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-testCompile</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Above same app I executed in java: I am getting an error(As expected)

Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to 
  create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[Test]] -> [To[Test]]] because 
  of No endpoint could be found for: Test, please check your classpath 
  contains the needed Camel component jar.

The same thing I am expecting from groovy script .. please suggest me if 
  I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving myself an answer to the above question. I haven't thought of executing a simple way of writing Groovy script. I have tried below code and it is working.

```
package org.apache.camel

import org.apache.camel.impl.*
import org.apache.camel.builder.*

def camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext()
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    def void configure() {
        from("Test")
                .to("Test")
    }
})
camelContext.start()

addShutdownHook{ camelContext.stop() }
synchronized(this){ this.wait() }
```

Maybe we can make execute above-posted question with the groovy script .. but I am not seeing any console logs when an error occurs. Please suggest me on this .. I really would like to know how the process executes .. thanks a lot advance.